# Angular routing with placeholder in default route

Tags: angular

I have a couple of routes defined that match to some components and then I have a catch-all route with a placeholder like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'some', component: SomeComponent },
  { path: 'other', component: OtherComponent },
  { path: ':route', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
  ];
```

I then have a PageNotFoundComponent like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-not-found',
  templateUrl: './page-not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-not-found.component.css']
})
export class PageNotFoundComponent implements OnInit {

  missingRoute: string;
  route: any;

  constructor( route: ActivatedRoute ) {
    this.route = route;
  }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.missingRoute = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('route');
  }
}
```

and a html file for the PageNotFoundComponent simply like this:

```
<p>The route {{missingRoute}} is not implemented.</p>
```

I have a component with some router links and router outlet (not shown here). If I click on the router links for *some* and *other* this works - in the sense that these components get displayed at the router-outlet. I also have two router-links that link to "*doesnotexist*" and "*doesnotexist2*". If I go to doesnotexist this is shown correctly (PageNotFound tells me about it), but if i then click on doesnotexist2 i get the same information as for doesnotexist: "The route doesnotexist is not implemented.". I was hoping to get "The route doesnotexist2 is not implemented."

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is happening because you are trying to navigate to the same root only route param is getting changed. So, in order to get the changed param instead of using `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('route');` just subscribe to route params something like

```
this.route.params.subscribe(data=>{
this.missingRoute =data['route']
});
```

Also why not you simple using private keyword in the constructor injection instead of defining property and assigning like

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute ) {

  }
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It helped me a lot. I accepted because you were 1st. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In your routes configuration your missing this:

```
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
```

Per [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration)

Once you have this, you'll have to capture the requested route so you can display `missingRoute`. This is covered in this part of the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#teach-authguard-to-authenticate)

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let url: string = state.url;

    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }

  checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
      return true;
    }

    // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
    this.authService.redirectUrl = url;

    // Navigate to the login page with extras
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It helped me a lot. I am currently going through the docs (this time reading until the end...)